# PyQt size() returns wrong size before showing the widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, size, pyqt5

I am trying to match the size of button1 to button2 by checking the size of button1 and then setting the size of button2 to match, but `size()` on button1 returns the incorrect value of (640, 480) unless I `show()` it first. But if I show it before I am done setting up my layouts it flickers on the screen while subsequent code runs which I don't want.

How can I get around this?

Here is a minimal example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
import random

class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("BUTTON1")

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100,100)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Button with sizeHint 100x100
    btn1 = MyButton()

    # There is a chance this button will be sized differently than its sizeHint wants
    if random.randint(0, 1):
        btn1.setFixedHeight(200)

    # This line works if btn1.setFixedHeight was called, but otherwise gives the wrong height of 480px
    height = btn1.size().height()

    # I want btn2 to be the same height as btn1
    btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON2")
    btn2.setFixedHeight(height)

    # Boilerplate
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(btn1)
    layout.addWidget(btn2)
    container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    container.setLayout(layout)
    container.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: As you realize, the geometry is updated only when necessary, that is, when it becomes visible, it observes the error. On the other hand you point out that you want both buttons to have the same height, but when using the QHBoxLayout that should not be a problem since that layout will make the buttons always have the same height. what's your objective?

Comment: @eyllanesc My actual objective was a lot more complicated, this is just a minimal example. I have a QVBoxLayout full of QHBoxLayouts and I need to align certain items in them along a vertical line. To do that I'm using spacers set to a fixed width calculated based on the size of the item being aligned and the items before it. The issue was that some items' sizeHints are overridden to a fixed size. S. Nick's answer helped, just needed to call resize() in addition to setting the fixed width before calling size()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QWidget::resize(int w, int h)
>
> This corresponds to resize(QSize(w, h)).
> Note: Setter function for property size.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
import random

class MyButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("BUTTON1")

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 100)

if __name__=='__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Button with sizeHint 100x100
    btn1 = MyButton()
    btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())                            # <========

# There is a chance this button will be sized differently than its sizeHint wants
#    if random.randint(0, 1):
#        btn1.setFixedHeight(200)
#        print("btn1 2->", btn1.size())

    # This line works if btn1.setFixedHeight was called, but otherwise gives the wrong height of 480px
    height = btn1.size().height()

    # I want btn2 to be the same height as btn1
    btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("BUTTON2")
    btn2.setFixedHeight(height)

    # Boilerplate
    layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(btn1)
    layout.addWidget(btn2)
    container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    container.setLayout(layout)
    container.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]